# EventHub 'send' in Java SDK hangs, send never occurs

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to use the sample code for sending a simple event to an Azure EventHub (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-get-started-send). It seems to go fine, I'm all configured, but when I get to the:

```
 ehClient.sendSync(sendEvent);
```

Part of the code, it just hangs there, and never gets past the sendAsync method. I'm using a personal computer, and have no firewall running. Is there some networking configuration I have to make maybe in Azure to allow this simple send to occur? Anyone have any luck making this work?

```
final ConnectionStringBuilder connStr = new ConnectionStringBuilder()
            .setNamespaceName("mynamespace")
            .setEventHubName("myeventhubname")
            .setSasKeyName("mysaskename")
            .setSasKey("mysaskey");

    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final EventHubClient ehClient = EventHubClient.createSync(connStr.toString(), executorService);

    print("Event Hub Client Created");
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            String payload = "Message " + Integer.toString(i);
            byte[] payloadBytes = gson.toJson(payload).getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
            EventData sendEvent = EventData.create(payloadBytes);

            // HANGS HERE - NEVER GETS PAST THIS CALL
            ehClient.sendSync(sendEvent);

        }

    } finally {
        ehClient.closeSync();
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use different executor service. For example 'work-stealing thread'

```
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
```

Comment: Thank you! My problem indeed turned out to be executor related. In hindsight the behavior I was seeing should have pointed me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-eventhubs</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-eventhubs-spark_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

import java.util.concurrent.{Executors, ScheduledExecutorService}
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.{EventData, EventHubClient}

object callToPushMessage{
private var executorService : ScheduledExecutorService = null 
def writeMsgToSink(message: PushMessage):Unit={
val connStr = ConnectionStringBuilder()
  .setNamespaceName("namespace")
  .setEventHubName("name")
  .setSasKeyName("policyname")
  .setSasKey("policykey").build


// The Executor handles all asynchronous tasks and this is passed to the EventHubClient instance.
// This enables the user to segregate their thread pool based on the work load.
// This pool can then be shared across multiple EventHubClient instances.
// The following code uses a single thread executor, as there is only one EventHubClient instance,
// handling different flavors of ingestion to Event Hubs here.
if (executorService == null) {
  executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()
}
val ehclient = EventHubClient.createSync(connStr,executorService)
try {
  val jsonMessage = new Gson().toJson(message,classOf[PushMessage])
  val eventData: EventData = EventData.create(jsonMessage.getBytes())
  ehclient.sendSync(eventData)

}
finally {
  ehclient.close()
  executorService.shutdown()
}
}}
```